# For QBS, What parameters would I set in my DynamicLibrary{} to install headers and libraries upon build?

Tags: qt, qmake, toolchain, dynamic-library, qbs

I am migrating my Qt Libraries over from qmake to qbs, and I am trying to find a decent template that will help me understand what parameters are needed for streamlining the building and installing of said libraries.

Currently a qbs file for one of my libraries looks like this:

```
import qbs

DynamicLibrary {
    name: "qparsingtoolkit";
    Depends {name: "cpp"}
    Depends {name: "Qt.core"}

    files: [
        "Headers/qparsingparameters.h",
        "Headers/qparsingtoolkit.h",
        "Headers/qparsingtoolkit_global.h",
        "Sources/qparsingparameters.cpp",
        "Sources/qparsingtoolkit.cpp",
    ]
}
```

The installation is relatively simple.

I just want a the headers placed in `/usr/include/qconsoledesigner`

and the `.so` libraries installed in 
`/usr/share/qconsoledesigner`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DynamicLibrary {
    name: "qparsingtoolkit";

    Depends {name: "cpp"}
    Depends {name: "Qt.core"}

    qbs.installPrefix: "usr"

    files: [
        "Sources/qparsingparameters.cpp",
        "Sources/qparsingtoolkit.cpp",
    ]

    Group {
        name: "api_headers"
        files: [
            "Headers/qparsingparameters.h",
            "Headers/qparsingtoolkit.h",
            "Headers/qparsingtoolkit_global.h",
        ]
        qbs.install: true
        qbs.installDir: "include/qconsoledesigner"
    }

    Group {
        fileTagsFilter: ["dynamiclibrary", "dynamiclibrary_symlink"]
        qbs.install: true
        qbs.installDir: "share/qconsoledesigner" 
    }
}
```

Note that installation of target binaries will become more straightforward in the future; see e.g. http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qbs/qml-qbsconvenienceitems-dynamiclibrary.html#installDir-prop.

A normal "qbs build" installs into an install root inside the build dir. To install "globally", follow the "qbs build" with "sudo qbs install --no-build --install-root /".

Comment: And just in case anyone is one of those types who doesnt read the manual, before running his commands on the bottom, remember to configure qbs: http://doc.qt.io/qbs/configuring.html -- I had to before his commands would work.